# iOS CoreData Relation: Use optional with or without minimum

Tags: ios, core-data, relationship

In core data you can set a relationship to optional but you can set it with minimum checked or without... Check the images below for the difference.
What **I think** I've noticed is that when you search for an object using a predicate like:`@"object != %@", objectToSearchFor`, the first setting returns nil's but the second setting doesn't. I can be mistaken about that but does anybody know the difference between the two settings?

[image: Optional relationship without minimum]

[image: Optional relationship with minimum]

P.s. I don't know if it matters but I'm using SQLite as DB engine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is some documentation about this in the [NSRelationshipDescription Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSRelationshipDescription_Class/NSRelationshipDescription.html):

> **Cardinality**
>   The maximum and minimum counts for a relationship
>   indicate the number of objects referenced (1 for a to-one
>   relationship, -1 means undefined). The counts are only enforced if the
>   relationship value in the containing object is not nil. That is,
>   provided that the relationship value is optional, there may be zero
>   objects in the relationship, which might be less than the minimum
>   count.

So for example, in the case of an optional to-many relationship: The value of the relationship must be either `nil`, or contain at least the minimum count of required objects.

In the case of an optional to-one relationship, the relationship value either is `nil` or points to another object, so I cannot think of a situation where it makes a difference whether the minimum count is 0 or 1.

All the constrains like minimum and maximum count etc. are checked when saving a managed object context.

Comment: I could not reproduce 'the first setting returns nil's but the second setting doesn't' so I guess it was something else. Thanks for the info!